# Does crate have an oplog to create a Meteor ddp driver from

Tags: meteor, crate

I'm looking to develop a Meteor ddp (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md) driver for crate db. Currently, Meteor has native support for mongodb. Redis support has been added via https://atmospherejs.com/slava/redis-livedata. Is there a white paper on the internal of crate from which I can work off from to create a crate ddp support for meteor or any ddp client. More specifically, does crate have a form of oplog through which changes to create data can be observed and propagated to clients.

Answer (score 0):

As crate is a distributed database, there is no central spot to listen for changes made to its documents. There is no central oplog.

Listening for changes would be most likely implemented using SQL TRIGGERS and the LISTEN/NOTIFY command like in postgresql:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-listen.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-notify.html

This is not implemented yet in crate.
We got this on our backlog but with a rather low priority.
You could file a github issue at https://github.com/crate/crate/issues to stress its importance and to give it some more attention.